# IOS using SWRevealView Library, How to close a sidebar when clicking on main view which contains a web view

Tags: ios, swift3, webview, swrevealviewcontroller, side-menu

I am using SWRevealViewController library for making side bar menu in IOS from the following link

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

Also I use the following code to close the sidebar if clicked outside

```
if revealViewController() != nil{

        btnLeftMenu.target = revealViewController()
        btnLeftMenu.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 275

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

    }
```

The problem is that I have a webview in my mainview so when the sidemenu opened then clicked on the webview,  I found that next page fires at webview but the sidemenu not closed :(

How to close the sidebar menu when clicking on the mainview which contains a webview.

[Screenshot for my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syj8m.jpg)

Comment: You need to implement the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method   `func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool` to allow your gesture recognizer work simultaneously with the built in gestures from webView

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but Could you write the full solution and clarification because I am pretty new to programming with IOS swift, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> can you try this

`sideMenu.target = revealViewController()
 sideMenu.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))`

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, But I already using it, but not closed also.